# Error while creating 1-to-1 relationship between two classes in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create 1-to-1 relationship between two classes. 1 user has 1 profile picture and 1 profile picture belongs to one user.

the code is as follows.

```
public class UserImage
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    public byte [] ImageContentBytes { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UserImage")]

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User_Has_Jobs_Posted> UserJobs { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; } // Adding relationship to the user.
    public IList<JobPost> jobPosts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]

    public virtual UserImage UserImage { get; set; }
        }
```

The error is saying:

```
 Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'FinalWorkFinder.Models.UserImage' and 'FinalWorkFinder.Models.ApplicationUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a one-to-one relationship one entry must depend on another, rather then both entries depending on each other.

So in your case an `ApplicationUser` entry would be valid on its own but a `UserImage` cannot.

You can fix this by using the `Required` attribute on the FK like so:

```
[Required]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Or you could use fluent api, and do something along the lines of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.UserImage)
    .WithRequired(s => s.User);
```

Comment: I added the [Required] above the User in the image class and I left the Inverseproperty as it is. I got an error saying: 
The type of property 'ImageId' on entity 'UserImage' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'UserImage_User'.

Comment: @CsibiNorbert oh I think thats because in `UserImage` you have defined the FK as the User property, which is type `ApplicationUser`, where the Id property in Application is probably `int` or `Guid`? So add a the property `public int UserId { set; get; }` and change the FK attribute to `ForeignKey("UserId")`

Comment: @CsibiNorbert Also depending on where you place the `ForiegnKey` attribute you may need to need to change the argument, you can see it here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx, but I'm not too sure what argument it expects above the PK

Comment: The user Id is a Guid not int, im so confused, the public int UserId { set; get; } already exist in the UserImage class

Comment: @CsibiNorbert my bad sorry, didn't see that but it should be `Guid` rather then string

Comment: Basically I just checked, it is string. so what exactly should I do?! :)

Comment: You will need to map the navigation property to the FK, which shown in the link I posted a few comments up but that won't be causing the error you mentioned, could you add the code for `IdentityUser` to the question please?